# How to configure socket.io to listen to client side

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, sockets, vue.js

I am new to using sockets and do not fully understand how they work.

When i load my website I get this error I just get this error "chat.js:4563 GET http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3Jn3vr 404 (Not Found)"

What am I missing? I am assuming I have to make the two ports work with one another somehow?

socket.js file:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat.message', function(message) {
     console.log('x: ' +  message)
  })
});
```

chat.js file:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io('http://localhost:80');

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    mounted() {
    },
    data: {
      message: null
    },
    methods: {
        send() {
            socket.emit('chat.message', this.message)
    }
}})
```

blade file:

```
@extends('dashboard.base')

@section('content')

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="fade-in">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="card mx-auto text-center w-50">
                    <div  class="card-header">
                        Live Chat
                    </div>
                    <div id="app" class="card-body">
                        <input v-model="message" type="text">
                        <span class="btn btn-success" @click="send">Send</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection

@section('javascript')
    <script src="{{ mix('js/chat.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
@endsection
```

Comment: make sure port 80 is not already being used by Apache

Comment: Your program may not actually be able to use :80 on some platforms. First rule of web server hacking: always use a higher pseudo-random port to test with. What happens if you use :1968?

Answer (score 0):

As both express and socket.io are using `http` they will share the same port. So you should listen to socket connections on port 3000 instead of port 80.

You could just initialize the socket object with `io` without the url, as it's on the same port as your express app. Socket.io will connect to the same host that serves the page

```
const socket = io();
```

The getting started page [here](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/#Integrating-Socket-IO) gives an overview of the same.

Comment: Thank you, leaving the parameters empty did not work but changing the port number did on my localhost; however i'm using ngrok to test this and on another pc im still getting the same error.

Comment: Maybe it is because you have the localhost url in the `io` connection. You could change that and test

Comment: I have tested this, it results in the same error and also breaks it on my pc.